# how to move tool strip to right end of a form?

Tags: winforms

I have a Tool strip in which i need to add some buttons. When i drag this tool strip on the form it is at the top of the form but i want this tool strip at the right end of the form. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the Dock property from `DockStyle.Top` to `DockStyle.Right`.

Comment: Thanks but now my Tool strip is not visible on the form. I have created some buttons on it too. Nothing on screen. Any idea?

Comment: Could be any number of things. Is the visible property set to false? Is there another control covering it up? You may need to post another question with code in it.